# Caught NoReverseMatch Error: Cauwhile rendering: Reverse for 'update_status' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: django

ght NoReverseMatch Error: Cauwhile rendering: Reverse for 'update_status' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

I'm following the tutorial: http://blog.pythonanywhere.com/35/

in the html file,

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url update_status %}"  >
  <input type="hidden" name="quote" value="{{quote}}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="access_token" value="{{access_token}}" />
  <input type="submit" value="Set as my status!"/>
</form>
```

In urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from regilink.myapp.views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^$', home),
    (r'^update_status/', update_status),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the name argument so, that it could be used

```
(r'^update_status/', update_status, name="update_status"),)
```